# C++ throwing class members

Tags: c++, exception, reference

I have the following C++ code

```
template <class E>
class ExceptionWrapper {
public:
    explicit ExceptionWrapper(const E& e): e(e) {}

    void throwException() {
        throw e;
    }

private:
    E e;
};

...
try {
    ExceptionWrapper<E> w(...);
    w.throwException();
} catch (const E& e) {
    ...
}
...
```

Question: is this code valid? I could argue that returning a reference to the class member is almost always not valid (and I am sure everybody agrees with this statement). However, my colleague claims that this is not the case with `throw`.

P.S. after changing `catch (const E& e)` to `catch (E e)` a nasty bug seemingly disappeared which strengthens my position - that this code is *not* valid.

Comment: the code above *should* be valid and catching by reference should work.
a) is your real code different to the above?
b) which compiler are you using?
throwing e *should* throw a copy of e.

Comment: A real example would be nice. Too much is missing/wrong in the sample.

Comment: @user2079303 yes it is. Sorry, my bad, I've made an edit.

Comment: "*I could argue that returning a reference to the class member is almost always not valid (and I am sure everybody agrees with this statement).*" I'd say that most of getters do this. They return const references to the members.

Comment: What do your colleagues claim is not the case with `throw` exactly? There is no syntax to throw anything by reference (except when rethrowing with `throw;`).

Comment: @user2079303 my claim is that catching e by reference is not valid since e is a member of w and w is not alive in the catch scope. Their claim is that e somehow gets copied when throw is executed. I don't understand this but am prepared to accept it once approved by some of stackoverflow's pros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> my claim is that catching e by reference is not valid since e is a member of w and w is not alive in the catch scope.

Your claim is incorrect. `throw e;` throws a copy of the member, and that copy is valid in catch's scope.

§ 15.1 / 3 (n3797 draft):

> **Throwing an exception copy-initializes (
>   8.5
>   ,
>    12.8
>   ) a temporary object**, called the
>   exception object
>   .  The
>   temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching
>   handler
>   (
>   15.3
>   ). If the
>   type of the exception object would be an incomplete type or a pointer to an incomplete type other than
>   (possibly cv-qualified)
>   void
>   the program is ill-formed. Evaluating a
>   throw-expression
>   with an operand throws
>   an exception; the type of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level
>   cv-qualifiers
>   from the
>   static type of the operand and adjusting the type from “array of
>   T
>   ” or “function returning
>   T
>   ” to “pointer to
>   T
>   ” or “pointer to function returning
>   T
>   ,” respectively.

Catching by const reference is the preferred way to catch exceptions. It allows catching derivatives of `std::exception` without slicing the exception object.

Comment: Exactly. And you should always catch by reference to avoid a second copy.

Comment: And any reference to any of the C++ standards confirming your position would be enough for me to accept your answer and thank you!

Comment: @Hindsight For a quickie, take a look at explanation in [throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) at cppreference. `First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression`. I'll take a look at the standard if I have time.

Comment: @Hindsight there you go, standard quoted.

Comment: You should specify that catching by *const* reference is the preferred way

Comment: Isn't storing a copy of type `E` in `e` potentially slicing as well?

Comment: @c45207 sure, if the template was instantiated with a parent class of the object actually passed to it, but I would assume that's not the use case for the wrapper. If it is, then it would have to store `e` by unique_ptr for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant point is :

> 15.1. **Throwing an exception:**
>
> *p3.* **A throw-expression initializes a temporary object**, called the exception object, the type of which is determined
> by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand of throw and adjusting the type
> from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”, respectively.
> **The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler (15.3).** If
> the type of the exception object would be an incomplete type or a pointer to an incomplete type other
> than (possibly cv-qualified) void the program is ill-formed. Except for these restrictions and the restrictions
> on type matching mentioned in 15.3, **the operand of throw is treated exactly as a function argument in a
> call (5.2.2) or the operand of a return statement.**

This is from the [draft for c++11](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), emphasis mine.

It basically means there is a temporary object created from the argument of `throw`. Just like there was a function `E f(){return private_e;}`, and that temporary is used as the argument for the appropriate handler. So you would have two possible copies actually if you didn't catch by reference.

Probably also relevant:

> *p5.* When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible,
> even if the copy/move operation is elided (12.8).

Answer (score -4):

If the constructor fails/throws, w doesn't exist. So "w.throwException()" is not valid.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Constructor does not fail/throw. Please consider this code as an academic example. I don't want comments on anything not directly related to the problem described in the question.

Comment: The constructor shown doesn't throw, and even if it did, the `w.throwException();` line would not be reached.